# Printing an object from an ArrayList, file cannot be found

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanted to make a program that reads user input in `TextField` and puts it into an `ArrayList` saved to a file. Then a button would allow the user to delete an object (containing name, ID and country an animal is imported from) from the `ArrayList` by entering the name of the animal they are looking for. This is the code for the method called when the delete button is pressed. I get a `FileNotFoundException` and I don't understand why. Would you help me, please?

```
    public void DeleteLine(String fileName,String strSearched){
            try {

                ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
                ObjectInputStream osTMP = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("ZooTMP.txt"));
                animal = (ArrayList<ANIMAL>) os.readObject();

                 System.out.println("Original contents of animal: ");
                  Iterator itr = animal.iterator();

                  while(itr.hasNext()) {
                     Object ANIMAL = itr.next();
                     if (ANIMAL.contains(strSearched) ) {

                         itr.remove();
                          }


                  }
                  System.out.println();

                    os.close();
                    osTMP.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Can't find the file Zoo.txt");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("The file Zoo.txt has already been closed");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.printf("Class is missing: %s\n",ex);
            }

        }
```

This is the interface ANIMAL:

```
package GUI_Try;

import java.io.*;

class ANIMAL implements Serializable {
    String name, ID, country;

    public ANIMAL(String name, String ID, String country){
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure `fileName` points to a file that is in the working directory of wherever you are launching your program.

Comment: What's the message in the FileNotFoundException? Is the filename an absolute path, or in the working directory? Does it exist? Consider adding some debugging code that prints or logs the filename, and tests whether the file exists -- `boolean isExtant = new File( fileName ).exists().`

Comment: It seems like when I load data from the file, the data is correctly read and all of it loaded. However, I can't find the file in my chosen directory. I cannot find it anywhere else either. The FileNotFoundException was caused by the unused `osTMP `. However, I still wonder where could this file be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, have you confirmed that the file is created in the same directory where the project is? Any sub-directories would have to be included in the filename.

Second, (and perhaps not pertinent) but you don't appear to use `osTMP` anywhere in your code, other than opening and closing the stream. Maybe this is the file that is causing the `FileNotFoundException`? Some information on the file architecture in the project file would be helpful. You could comment out one line or the other at a time and figure out which file is causing this exception, which would assist in fixing the issue as well.

Comment: I followed your advices. It seems like the `FileNotFoundException` was caused by the unused osTMP. Afterwords my code stopped executing at the line `if (ANIMAL.equals(strSearched) ) {`, because my file contains an `ArrayList`, each object of which has three fields: `name`, `ID` and `country`. Obviously, `strSearched` is never equal to all three fields, so this if statement is never true. Do you know how could I check if the `ArrayList` object contains a given name? I tried using `contains` in various ways, but I always got an error.

Comment: My mistake in the above comment, the line is `if (ANIMAL.contains(strSearched) ) {` and here I get the error message: `The method contains(String) is undefined for the type Object`. Do you know how could I check if the name of the  `ArrayList` object is for example `lion`, or even better, how could I check if a given string is contained inside the whole object? Thank you.

Comment: You could add a line after `Object ANIMAL = itr.next()` which says something like `String str = ANIMAL.name;` and then compare `str` and `strSearched` in your if condition.

Comment: At the line  `String str = ANIMAL.name;` I get the error message: `name cannot be resolved or is not a field`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you give more information on what's inside the `ANIMAL` type? That error only returns if there isn't an accessible property inside `ANIMAL` called `name`.

Comment: I posted the code of the interface ANIMAL. It is composed of three `String`s, all in a single object of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer - Make the `String` declaration `public String...` or add methods that return each value. Right now, it's probably not accessible since you didn't declare the values public.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, it really went a long way! Eventually I managed to fix my mistakes, but wouldn't have done it without you. :) Have a great day!